# How can I import a VCF genome file?

Tags: import

I had my exome sequenced and now I have a large [VCF file](http://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/vcf4.0/) (Variant Call Format version 4.0). This is a file format for encoding structural variations in VCF 4.0 format.

I'd like to import it and start exploring, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you think should it look like within *Mathematica* after importing? You can certainly use `Import[filename, "Table"]` and strip off the file headers in before the column headers, before possibly converting to a `Dataset[]`.